# not able to launch a background process to run php script in windows IIS server

Tags: php, iis

I am trying to launch a background process( executing php script) using `popen / exec`.

i tried with `proc_open` --- but results in infinite loop & terminates after some time with **500 internal error**.

with `popen/exec` -- no error & at the same time background script is not running as well.

my current structure is like :

test.php

```
$processHandle = popen("start /b php background.php", "r");
```

background.php

```
$file = fopen("test.txt","w");
 echo fputs($file,"Hello World. Testing!");
 fclose($file);
```

i tried through command prompt : php **test.php**

it's launching the background process, and file gets created

i tried to run the same script through web browser request:
  it's not working & not giving error as well.

any help please ?

Comment: what OS you are using?

Answer (score 0):

```
pclose(popen());
```

or

```
$var = popen();
pclose($var);
```

Comment: thank you. I tried that thing as well it's not working. here the main problem is launching the background process itself. does it related to pclose() ?

Comment: probably it is execution time error.... probably... but in your case.. the stream is still open might go reach maximum execution time... if you want to run a background process... try exec().. and inside the exec.. append nohup.. "nohup php background.php"

Comment: i tried that now the problem is Warning: exec(): Unable to fork [nohup php C:\wwwroot\api\test\background.php] in C:\wwwroot\api\test\test.php on line 11 ..

Comment: Because nohup is linux command. There's no windows command equivalent for it. You can try 'start' but when you match it stream like popen it will result to infinite runtime because it stays there as long as it could.. you can try to put exit(); in the php file.. or just add '&' at the end... 'php background.php &'

Comment: should i put exit() in test.php or background.php .. i tired both but with no luck.